# nopcommerce: Not displayed "logged in" in http pages

Tags: ssl, https, nopcommerce

I've activated SSL for my website, only for checkout pages, admin area and register, and these pages work good, but other pages (which is under HTTP) are not showing that I am "logged in".When I set "Force SSL for all site pages" I am able to see "logged in", but I don't want use https for this pages...How can I fix it?

Use nop 3.8

```
set "SSL enabled"=true
set "Secure URL" = https://myStore.com/
```

in web.config set:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="NOPCOMMERCE.AUTH" loginUrl="~/login" protection="All" timeout="43200" path="/" requireSSL="true" slidingExpiration="true" />
</authentication>
```

and

```
  <providers>
    <add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="localhost" accessKey="" ssl="true" />
  </providers>
```

Comment: What is your default store URL? If it uses www prefix thats the reason it cant find the auth cookie

Comment: Thanks for answer, yes ,problem was in URL,exactly in sup-domain. I have site with url like : store.mysite.com , and I mast  to write in web.config :
` <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="NOPCOMMERCE.AUTH" loginUrl="~/login" protection="All" timeout="43200" **domain=".mysite.com"** path="/" requireSSL="false" slidingExpiration="true" />
    </authentication>`